# Unique maximum flow

Tags: graph-theory

Is there an efficient algorithm for determining whether or not a flow network has an unique maximum flow. I do not mean the actual value (which of course is unique) but the function $f : E \to R$ that gives this value.

Comment: I'd like to ask for a bit more clarity as to the objective function being maximized.  If a network has only one source and one sink, then I'd grant "maximum flow" can have only one meaning and the extent to which flows on edges are unique can be determined as @gt6989b suggests.  However more complex networks, with multiple sources and/or sinks, suggest a more careful analysis of how the problem translates into linear programming formulations might be needed.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to translate this to a linear programming formulation, and then what you are asking is whether the optimal solution is unique. I believe all modern solvers are able to tell you that...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use min-cost $b$-flow, to decide this in polynomial time.

First calculate the min cost $\lambda$ of a $0$-flow by inserting a bachwards arc $(t,s)$ with cost $-1$ and high capacity (set all other costs to $0$).

Now set $b(s)=\lambda,b(t)=-\lambda$ and for all other vertices $b(v)=0$. If you set for example $c(e)=1, c(e')=0$, for $e'\neq e$ the min-cost b-flow will be a max-flow with least possible flow on the edge $e$. If you set $c(e)=-1$ the min-cost b-flow will be a max-flow with maximum possible flow on $e$.

Now the flow is of course unique if and only if for every edge the minimum possible flow on that edge is equal to the maximum possible flow on that edge for every max-flow.